# How can I call xmlns:languageUtil in title img property?

Tags: xslt, liferay

I have some images in a xsl page, sth like that:

```
<xsl:if test="/root/dynamic-element[@name='Aigua']/dynamic-content='true'">
    <img title= "$languageUtil:get($locale,'dipta.recurs.espai.natural.gastronomia')" id   ="Aigua" style = "witdh:40px;height:40px;"  src="/marc/estils/imatges/espaisNaturals/Aigua.png"></img>  
</xsl:if>
```

And I like to show some info, when pass the mouse over image,  but i just see languageUtil:get($locale,'dipta.recurs.espai.natural.gastronomia') not the real value, what i'm doing worong? 
My knowledge about xslt is real poor. 
ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i believe i find out a solution:

```
  <xsl:if test="/root/dynamic-element[@name='Aigua']/dynamic-content='true'">
       <img title="" id ="Aigua" style = "witdh:40px;height:40px;" src="/marc/estils/imatges/espaisNaturals/Aigua.png">
           <xsl:attribute name="title">
              <xsl:value-of select="languageUtil:get($locale,'dipta.recurs.espai.natural.gastronomia')"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
      </img>             
           &#160;  

  </xsl:if>
```

you need to acces to property to modificate, and when it's selected show info.